# Select All checkbox to select nested angular ng-repeat checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a series of nested ng-repeat checkboxes, where it's a structure like:

- Checkbox

  - country
  - country
  - select all
- Checkbox

  - country
  - country
  - select all

The "select all" in each group should select all "country" checkboxes in that group.

You can see it in action here: http://plnkr.co/edit/rBIv9lfOr5MASPia7ORS?p=preview

The inner checkboxes are generated by an array in the main json:

```
  $scope.carriers = 
  [{
    "name": "UPS",
    "selected": false,
    "hasPaymentOptions": false,
    "isSelectable": true,
    "value": "",
    "countries": [
        "USA","UK","Canada","Germany","Australia"
     ]
   },etc
```

And are in a nested ng-repeat:

```
<!-- main list of carrier checkboxes -->
    <div ng-repeat="c in partnerent.carriers.carriers" class="spacer-top-md spacer-bottom-md">
      <div class="carrier spacer-bottom-sm">
        <div class="checkbox-inline">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="{{c.name | slug}}" ng-model="c.selected"> {{c.name}}
          </label>
        </div>
        <!-- inner checkboxes for countries -->
        <ul class="entitlement-countries list-inline">
          <li ng-repeat="ec in c.countries">
            <div class="checkbox-inline">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="{{ec | slug}}"> {{ec}}
              </label>
            </div>
            </li>
            <li ng-if="c.countries.length > 0">
              <div class="checkbox-inline">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="{{ec | slug}}_selectall"> Select all
                </label>
              </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

It all works, but my question is how to have those "select all" checkboxes select their group of countries?  Most of the solutions and directives I've found involve the model and are generally for one group of checkboxes, where I have several inside a ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plunker of my answer: http://plnkr.co/edit/d4cV1VP5iPj58ePGvZNR

***Note: I didn't change all of the carriers, just the first one in the Plunker***

How I would approach this would be to have some sort of `ng-change` method on the selectAll & the child checkboxes:

```
<ul class="entitlement-countries list-inline">
    <li ng-repeat="ec in c.countries">
        <div class="checkbox-inline">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="{{ec.name | slug}}" ng-model="ec.selected" ng-change="checkAllCountriesSelected(c)"> {{ec}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li ng-if="c.countries.length > 0">
        <div class="checkbox-inline">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="{{c.name | slug}}_selectall" ng-model="c.selectAll" ng-change="checkAllCountriesSelected(c)"> Select all
            </label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the data model would change slightly to:

```
$scope.carriers = 
  [{
    "name": "UPS",
    "selected": false,
    "selectAll": false,
    "hasPaymentOptions": false,
    "isSelectable": true,
    "value": "",
    "countries": [
        { name: "USA", selected: false },
        { name: "UK", selected: false },
        { name: "Canada", selected: false },
        { name: "Germany", selected: false },
        { name: "Australia", selected: false }
     ]
   },etc
```

And I'd add the change methods:

```
$scope.checkCountryToggled = function checkCountryToggled (carrier) {
    var carrierCountriesSelected = getSelectedCountries(carrier);

    if (carrierCountriesSelected.length === carrier.countries.length) {
        carrier.selectAll = true;
    } else {
        carrier.selectAll = false;
    }
};

function getSelectedCountries (carrier) {
    var selectedCountries = filterFilter(carrier.countries, function (country) {
        return country.selected;
    });

    return selectedCountries || [];
}

$scope.checkSelectAllToggled = function (carrier) {
    if (carrier.selectAll) {
         selectAllCountries(carrier);
    }
};

function selectAllCountries (carrier) {
    angular.forEach(carrier.countries, function (country) {
        country.selected = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: Very nice.  Thanks. I was confused initially since of course each carrier has its own countries array.  I didn't think of making a function and passing the array.

Comment: i ran into this a lot in my early days of Angular...things like ng-checked & ng-model tend to screw your brain up on how to handle the changing values...ng-change is a nice directive because it allows you to evaluate your model only after its changed...comes in handy if you ever work with ngModelOptions (available in 1.3)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-checked` directive to select all the checkboxes.

```
<ul class="entitlement-countries list-inline">
  <li ng-repeat="ec in c.countries">
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="{{ec | slug}}" ng-checked="c.countries.selectAll"> {{ec}}
      </label>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li ng-if="c.countries.length > 0">
      <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="{{ec | slug}}_selectall" ng-model="c.countries.selectAll"> Select all
        </label>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/o2NOBmFYZMtfkBu4lTrs?p=preview

Comment: That will work until he have to retrieve which country is selected in which case `ng-checked` will not change models of single countries and return false model

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem because whenever the select all is unselected, all of the countries will be deselected.